# Is there a difference between ほんとう (hontō) and ほんとうに (hontō-ni) when used alone as interjection or question?

Tags: word-choice, particle-に, adverbs, interjections

As the equivalent of Enlgish "Oh really?" / "Yes really." as lone utterances I seem to hear both "本当" (hontō) and "本当に" (hontō-ni) in Japanese - is there a difference?

It seems that hontō is a noun and -ni changes it into an adverb but that this doesn't really matter for the purpose of such simple utterances. Am I thinking along the right lines?

Comment: My favorite way of saying "What, really?" is 「本当に本当！？」 >^.^<

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference in utterances for both words, if you speak those alone.

But if you add some words after that, you might need to use "本当に~" to get correct grammar.